# How can I remove objects with empty strings from array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that looks like this.

```
var array = [{"Capital":5},{"":""},{"Kichler":6},{"Minka Aire":4},{"Savoy House":2},{"":""},{"":""}]
```

I want to remove all of the objects with empty strings so it would then look like this...

```
var array = [{"Capital":5},{"Kichler":6},{"Minka Aire":4},{"Savoy House":2}]
```

I have tried to write a for loop the compares each item in the array to {"":""} but it still returns false even for those empty objects.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have an object and want to check if an empty string is a key, `"" in obj` will return true

Comment: So use that fact, along with `array.filter(obj => {})`, to filter out all the objects where `"" in obj`

Comment: Hi I'm pretty sure research would have indicated that removing *any* sort of entry from an array in Javascript is typically done with `filter`.  Failure to do sufficient research is a valid down-vote reason (hover over the down-vote button for a question), so researching will help you avoid such down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method that creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
Then unpack key value from object and return on the basics of blank key and value

```js
var array = [{"Capital":5},{"":""},{"Kichler":6},{"Minka Aire":4},{"Savoy House":2},{"":""},{"":""}]

let result = array.filter((i) => { 
 let [key, value] = (Object.entries(i)).flat();
 return !(key == "" && value == "");
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update my answer because there is a totally short option which works like charm:

```js
const array = [{"Capital":5},{"":""},{"Kichler":6},{"Minka Aire":4},{"Savoy House":2},{"":""},{"":""}];
const result = array.filter(e => e[''] !== '');
console.log(result);
```

Simple `filter()` with the above condition.

**Original answer:**

So basically it is totally fine if you have keys in an object named as an empty string just like in your example. Which means you can find easily those by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to filter them out.

Based on that you can adapt [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) just like the following:

```js
const array = [{"Capital":5},{"":""},{"Kichler":6},{"Minka Aire":4},{"Savoy House":2},{"":""},{"":""}];
const result = array.filter(e => !Object.keys(e).includes(''));
console.log(result);
```

Read further here about the used methods:

1. [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
3. [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

I hope that helps!